# unreadable font in browser

Tags: unity, fonts, 17.04

I change my font by setting up `.fonts.conf` :

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
 <match target="pattern">
  <test name="family" qual="any">
   <string>sans-serif</string>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" binding="same" name="family">
   <string>Vazir</string>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <dir>~/.fonts</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

but it change my font in a way that in some website I can't even read them.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSotl.png)

I even try to change my font and set them in default way by unity-tweak-tool but it didn't work.

Comment: I think that's because you're attempting to display Latin characters in a font intended for use with Farsi (the Vazir font-family)?

Comment: @sempaiscuba, so can I separate my usage of font of English and Farsi ? although I found out that if I assign the Farsi font to `Arial` too it would solve my problem and I don't no why? :-). can I set font size for Farsi font not English?

Comment: If the content-language of the page is specified in the page header, then it should be straightforward.  Simply assign the default font as, say, Ariel for example, and use the Vazir font when content-language is set to Farsi .  Of course, if the page authors haven't specified the content-language attribute then you could have a problem!